Deduce constructor argument types for a class template in C++?
I need to write a template function in C++ that extracts the types of a class's constructor arguments and returns them as a std::tuple. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct get_tuple
{
    // return the types of T's constructor arguments as a tuple
    // using type = ...
};

struct Test
{
    Test(int, double) {}
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename get_tuple<Test>::type, std::tuple<int, double>>);


I tried the following code, but it failed because we cannot obtain a function pointer to the constructor.
template <class T, class... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> get_tuple_impl(T (*)(Args...));

template <class T>
struct get_tuple
{
    using type = decltype(get_tuple_impl(&T::T));
};


What I want to achieve is a factory that creates instances of T based on parameters provided in a config. like
template<class T>
T construct()
{
    typename get_tuple<T>::type args;
    // fill args with config
    return std::make_from_tuple<T>(args);
}


What happens if there are more than one ctor? In your example, Test also has copy ctor, how are we/compiler supposed to know which ctor's parameter to extract.

What could possibly work is what boost.pfr does to detect types of struct members (make a class with a templated operator T, try passing it to the constructor, use stateful metaprogramming to extract the type it got converted to). But this can get quite complicated.

The question is also unclear. What happen is there are two ctor as for you class Test. How can we possible infer argument type from just get_tuple<Test>

Is your goal to know the possible argument types or to know if a given type is constructible from arguments of some types?

"I need to write a template function in C++ that extracts the types of a class's constructor..." Why? What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve.

The edit still doesn't clarify what should happen when there are more than one ctor.

@user12002570 Only consider the case where there is one ctor.

@JcflyLv Your example Test has 3 constructors

@JcflyLv Your given class Test actually has multiple constructors. Note that c++ is one of the most difficult/complicated languages to learn. A good c++ book should help clear why Test has multiple ctors.

You cannot call a constructor.  Instead of doing this, if it is indeed needed, you can adda tuple to each class and populate that tuple with the types you want.  Then you can pass the class type as a template parameter and access the tuple like class_name::ctor_args_tuple

Thanks to @HolyBlackCat. After studying boost.fpr, I finally worked it out
#include <tuple>
#include <array>

struct ubiq_constructor
{
    std::size_t ignore;

    template <class T>
    constexpr operator T() const { return T{}; }
};

template <class T, std::size_t I0, std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto arg_count(std::size_t &out, std::index_sequence<I0, I...>)
    -> typename std::add_pointer<decltype(T{ubiq_constructor{I0}, ubiq_constructor{I}...})>::type
{
    out = sizeof...(I) + 1;
    return nullptr;
}

template <class T, std::size_t... I>
constexpr void arg_count(std::size_t &out, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    arg_count<T>(out, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(I) - 1>{});
}

template <class T>
constexpr std::size_t arg_count()
{
    std::size_t count{};
    arg_count<T>(count, std::make_index_sequence<10>());
    return count;
}

//
template <class T>
struct identity
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <std::size_t Index>
using size_t_ = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Index>;

#define REGISTER_TYPE(Type, Index)                   \
    constexpr std::size_t type_to_id(identity<Type>) \
    {                                                \
        return Index;                                \
    }                                                \
    constexpr Type id_to_type(size_t_<Index>)        \
    {                                                \
        return Type{};                               \
    }

REGISTER_TYPE(double, 1)
REGISTER_TYPE(int, 2)

template <std::size_t I>
struct ubiq_val
{
    std::size_t *ref_;

    template <class Type>
    constexpr operator Type() const noexcept
    {
        ref_[I] = type_to_id(identity<Type>{});
        return Type{};
    }
};

template <class T, std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto get_type_ids(std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(I)> types{};
    T tmp{ubiq_val<I>{types.data()}...};
    (void)tmp;

    return types;
}

template <class T, std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto get_tuple_impl(std::index_sequence<I...> seq)
{
    constexpr auto types = get_type_ids<T>(seq);
    return std::tuple<decltype(id_to_type(size_t_<types[I]>{}))...>{};
}

template <class T>
constexpr auto get_tuple()
{
    constexpr std::size_t count = arg_count<T>();
    return get_tuple_impl<T>(std::make_index_sequence<count>{});
}

struct Test
{
    constexpr Test(int, double) {}
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(get_tuple<Test>()), std::tuple<int, double>>);
    return 0;
}

However, it requires the constructor of Test to be constexpr.

However, this approach doesn't work for classes without default constructors.
The issue you're facing is due to the fact that constructors are special member functions that can't be taken by address or used as function pointers directly. However, you can use SFINAE (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error) techniques to deduce the argument types of a constructor.
Here's an updated implementation:
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

// Helper struct to extract constructor argument types
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct get_constructor_args;

// Specialization for non-aggregate initialization
template <typename T>
struct get_constructor_args<T, std::void_t<decltype(T{std::declval<std::add_pointer_t<T>>()})>>
{
    static constexpr auto size = 0;
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

// Specialization for aggregate initialization
template <typename T>
struct get_constructor_args<T, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(std::tuple_element_t<0, T>) > 1)>>
{
    static constexpr auto size = sizeof...(std::tuple_element_t<0, T>);
    using type = std::tuple<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::get<0>(std::declval<T>()))>...>;
};

// Specialization for single-argument constructors
template <typename T, typename Arg>
struct get_constructor_args<T, std::void_t<decltype(T{std::declval<Arg>()})>>
{
    static constexpr auto size = 1;
    using type = std::tuple<Arg>;
};

// General case: try to find a matching constructor
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct get_constructor_args<T, std::void_t<decltype(T{std::declval<Args>()...})>>
{
    static constexpr auto size = sizeof...(Args);
    using type = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

Now, your get_tuple struct becomes simple:
template <class T>
struct get_tuple : public get_constructor_args<T> {};

And here's how you can define your construct function:
template <class T>
T construct() {
    typename get_tuple<T>::type args;
    // Fill args from configuration...
    return std::apply([](auto&&... args){ return T(args...); }, args);
}

This solution uses SFINAE to detect which specialization matches the given type T. The first specialization handles cases where no constructor is found (e.g., when T has only deleted constructors). The second specialization covers aggregate initialization. The third one deals with single-argument constructors, while the last one tries to match multiple-argument constructors.
Please note that this solution assumes that all constructors have distinct parameter lists; if there are overloaded constructors with different numbers of arguments, this will not work correctly. Also, keep in mind that this does not handle move-only types well since they require lvalue references to their arguments during construction.
Example usage:
int main() {
    struct MyType { MyType(int, int) {} };
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename get_tuple<MyType>::type, std::tuple<int, int>>);
    
    struct AnotherType { AnotherType(double) {} };
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename get_tuple<AnotherType>::type, std::tuple<double>>);
    
    struct AggregateType { int x; double y; };
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename get_tuple<AggregateType>::type, std::tuple<int, double>>);
    
    return 0;
}



The code seems unable to compile under g++.
